# javascript/jquery - add debounce to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, throttling

I want to add a debounce to a button, but i want to perform some actions each time user clicks button, but only after 5 second after user hits button, then perform SQL update.  Usually the throttle seems to be applied directly to the listener.  Here I want some actions performed each time the button is clicked, and then an update after a reasonable waiting period.

I am not sure how to use the function in this case...

reference: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    // do a date calculation
    // show user changes to screen
    // wait until user has has stopped clicking the 
             // button for 5 seconds, then update file with "process" function.

});

function process(){
    // update database table
}
```

### debounce  syntax

```
$('input').bind('keyup blur', $.debounce(process, 5000));
```

Comment: So you don't know how `$.debounce` works or what is your problem? *Edit:* Ah I see....

Comment: I added details about my question.  debounce and throttling is an pattern often used in ajax. Here is some good reading... http://ajaxpatterns.org/Submission_Throttling

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could still use `$.debounce` like so:

```
// create new scope
(function() {
     // create debounced function
     var dprocess = $.debounce(process, 5000);

     // bind event handler
     $('#myButton').click(function() {
         // do a date calculation
         // show user changes to screen
         // call the function
         dprocess();
     });
}());
```

Alternative without `$.debounce` (you can always debounce your code this way, without jQuery):

```
// create new scope
(function() {
     var timer;

     // bind event handler
     $('#myButton').click(function() {
         if(timer) {
             clearTimeout(timer);
         }
         // do a date calculation
         // show user changes to screen
         // call the function
         timer = setTimeout(process, 5000);
     });
}());
```

Comment: Tthis looks like the right direction. You are wrapping an anonymous function around the process? Will dprocess() be in scope when called?

Comment: You mean whether it will be reachable from the click event handler? Yes. I added the immediate function call so that `dprocess` does not leak into global scope. Of course you can remove this if e.g. your code is inside a `ready` event handler anyway.

Comment: Very nice jQuery-less debounce example. It almost negates the need for jQuery. Almost...

Answer (score 14):

Debounce using native/vanilla JS and jquery/underscore.js.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nzC8P/1/)

**JS**

```
//Native/Vanilla JS
document.getElementById('dvClickMe').onclick = debounce(function(){
    alert('clicked - native debounce'); 
}, 250);


function debounce(fun, mil){
    var timer; 
    return function(){
        clearTimeout(timer); 
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            fun(); 
        }, mil); 
    };
}

//jQuery/Underscore.js
$('#dvClickMe2').click(_.debounce(function(){
    alert('clicked - framework debounce'); 
}, 250));
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='dvClickMe'>Click me fast! Native</div>
<div id='dvClickMe2'>Click me fast! jQuery + Underscore</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var timer;
 $('#myButton').click(function() {
     //Called every time #myButton is clicked         
     if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = setTimeout(process, 5000);
 });

function process(){
  //Called 5000ms after #myButton was last clicked 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a global variable might not be the best solution if the debounce function is used to debounce multiple functions. For that we should scope the timer to the function being denounced.

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 2000) {
  if (func.timer) clearTimeout(func.timer);
  func.timer = setTimeout(func, timeout);
}

debounce(func1, 4000);
debounce(func2, 1000);
```

NOTE: this won't work with an anonymous function;

Answer (score -4):

Why not just use `setTimeOut(function() { process(); }, 5000);`

Comment: As I understand, this just adds a delay. I want to ignore initial clicks and then just run update when user has calmed down for a few seconds.

Comment: Fair enough. You could implement that similarly without debounce, but it seems like that is probably the way to go.