# How to get/catch event off screen element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make fixed table header and is it possible to catch event or catch element when you scroll down and table header goes off screen?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you give me some code? example?

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: container.addEventListener("scroll", fnDoStuff, true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be using a scroll event for the window, and check if the element is visible there.

How to check if an element is on screen is answered here: [Check if element is visible on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353934/check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen)

Here's how to turn that code into custom events entered_view and exited_view:

```
var $element = $('#some_element');
var is_visible = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    // Check if $element is on screen using code from other answer

    if (checkVisible($element)) {
         if (!is_visible) {
             $element.trigger('entered_view');
         }
         is_visible = true;
    } else {
         if (is_visible) {
             $element.trigger('exited_view');
         }
         is_visible = false;
    }
});
```

Once you get it working, you might also want to debounce the scroll event: [Here's info about debouncing/throttling in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055923/javascript-jquery-add-debounce-throttle-to-a-button).

Comment: you probably want to debounce that because scroll can fire dozens of times a second...

Comment: @dandavis Yes that's absolutely correct, just was trying to keep the answer simpler / complexity down. edited to reflect

Comment: you're right and nice to to provide code, i was just trying to make good gooder in case a noob came across the code and wondered why it bogged down their crappy device (detecting visibility can be expensive)...