# How to limit or throttle the number of function calls (in order to increase performance) in this function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I have a function that look like this:

```
function someFunction(text) {
    $('.class').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().match(text)) {
           $this.addClass('found');
        } else {
           $this.removeClass('found');
        }
    });
}
```

and that function is executed in keyup event,

```
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
   someFunction($(this).val());
});
```

on IE if there are lot of `.class` elements it can be slow, I thought that I could speed things up if I stop executing the each call if the function have been executed again before each is finished. How can I do this?

Comment: [javascript/jquery - add debounce (throttle) to a button](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8056049/2025923)

Comment: that will not happen.. since js/browser is single threaded when `someFunction` is being executed no new event handler will get called

Comment: [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: what you could try is some kind of debouncing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could speed this up by adding a slight delay to the `keyup` handler so that the DOM is only affected after typing has ended instead of on each keystroke. You can also use the `:contains` selector to find the elements. Try this:

```
function someFunction(text) {
    $('.class').removeClass('found').filter(':contains("' + text + '")').addClass('found');
}

var timer;
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        someFunction(this.value);
    }, 100);
});
```

Also, as mentioned by @A.Wolff you could cache the `.class` selector, but this would only work if no `.class` elements are dynamically added to the DOM while you're searching:

```
var $elements = $('.class');
function someFunction(text) {
    $elements.removeClass('found').filter(':contains("' + text + '")').addClass('found');
}

var timer;
$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        someFunction(this.value);
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: setTimeout with 100 ms delay is exactly what I've done already, thought that there is a better way.

Comment: Ya and maybe `$('.class')` could be cached

Comment: @jcubic there isn't really many options in this case unfortunately. You're bound by the weight of data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  **return false;**  end of your function

```
function someFunction(text) {
    $('.class').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().match(text)) {
           $this.addClass('found');
        } else {
           $this.removeClass('found');
        }

    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will break each after first element, not when you call that function again.

Comment: @jcubic the question title "break jQuery each function call when calling again" is really unclear wording as to what your goal is, therefore I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 0):

As I misunderstood the question, here're two optimizations instead (both can be used together):

### Cache the query result, only occasionally updating it by timer

Not really beautiful but may provide a robust solution given that the performance gain is critical.

```
window.lastValue = null;

window.cachedElements = null;

window.updateCachedElements = function(){ cachedElements = $('.class'); };

function someFunction() {
    cachedElements.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().match(lastValue)) {
           $this.addClass('found');
        } else {
           $this.removeClass('found');
        }
    });
}

$('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {
    if(cachedElements === null) {
        updateCachedElements();
    }

    lastValue = $(this).val()

    someFunction();
});

setInterval(function(){ updateCachedElements(); someFunction(); }, 500);
```

### Use debounce (a form of throttling) to minimize number of `someFunction` calls to 1/100ms or 10 per second

After (and *outside*) the `someFunction` definition, do:

```
someFunction = debounce(someFunction, 100);
```

Debounce implementation from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html):

```
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;

    var later = function() {
        var last = (Date.now || new Date().getTime()) - timestamp;

        if (last < wait && last >= 0) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
        } else {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) {
                result = func.apply(context, args);
                if (!timeout) context = args = null;
            }
        }
    };

    return function() {
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        timestamp = _.now();
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        if (!timeout) timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) {
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            context = args = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
};
```