# jQuery trigger action only 1 time when key down

Tags: jquery, html

In jQuery, we can use 'window.onkeydown' to trigger action when a key is pressed. But 'onkeydown' will 'continuously' execute the function that we have assigned for the trigger. Is there a way that we can execute the assigned function only one time? Thank you!

On key down is specially annoying when I do something like:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 17){
    jQuery('<h2/>').appendTo($('#myDiv'))
  }
}
```

In this case, as long as I hold down the Ctrl key (keyCode 17), jQuery will continuously create h2 elements inside the #myDiv, and the result I want is just 1 h2 is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use jQuery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to have the event execute once and only once. The event is unbound after it occurs:

> The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a
>   given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation.

```
jQuery(window).one('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 17){
        jQuery('<h2/>').appendTo($('#myDiv'))
      }
});
```

If you need the event to continue to be bound after it executes, you'd probably instead need to look at something like [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055923/javascript-jquery-add-debounce-throttle-to-a-button) to limit executions.

Comment: Hi, I did solve the problem with another path. But thank you very much for your answer. Have a good day :)